# Error : Could not retrieve list of models from database?

Tags: ros, household-objects-database

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm working with household_objects_database , Service [/objects_database_node/get_model_mesh] is available.
,but I got this error :

- Could not retrieve list of models
  from database

I have downloaded the database manually from here:

- http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/model_database

and I'm not sure that I have put it in the right place !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58978/error-:-could-not-retrieve-list-of-models-from-database-!/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-22**:
@ricky
@Matei Ciocarlie
@Rookdroid
@jontromanab

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2013-03-22**:
Can you be more specific? Since we don't know what your execution steps are, what you have installed, and other details related to this issue.

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-23**:
I have installed a postgreSQl server then I have installed household_objects_database from this link : http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database
at the last step of installing the database , I have an error  telling me that it can not access the remote access , ....

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-23**:
@dejanpan  has answered me and told me to download the database models from here :
http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/model_database

that's the link of the question I'm talking about  :
http://answers.ros.org/question/12610/accessing-the-household_object_database-remotely-from-willowgarag

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-23**:
Also, I have downloaded the pr2_object_manipulation stack, that includes the tabletop_object_detector  , and when I type this commands :
roscore , roslaunch household_objects_database objects_database_local_server.launch , roslaunch tabletop_object_detector tabletop_object_recognition.launch .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The last command has given me the mentioned error in my question !

---

Originally posted by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) with karma: 238 on 2013-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0